# How do I call a function from my JS file in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, google-api

I'm trying to call the function that I have written in the JS file, however, nothing is happening when I run the server. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong and I could really use some guidance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="group.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="emailForm">
    <input type="text" name="e">
    <input type="submit" onclick="addEmail(e)" value="Submit">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
...
function addEmail(e){
    alert("test");
    user = {
        email: e,
        role: "MEMBER"
    };
    var group = "test@googlegroups.com";
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/'+ group +'/members',{ method: 'POST', body: $scope.user })
    .then(res => res.json()) 
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

Comment: Try to put the `<script>` tags right before the `</body>`

Comment: Is the script being loaded? Any error in the console?

Comment: It's getting the JS file successfully

Answer (score 0):

remove the parameter from the function in js code.

```
function addEmail(){
var e=document.getElementById('email');
alert("test");
user = {
    email: e,
    role: "MEMBER"
};
var group = "test@googlegroups.com";
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/'+ group 
+'/members',{ method: 'POST', body: $scope.user })
.then(res => res.json()) 
.then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

and in HTML also add ID to input tag and call js function without parameter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="group.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="emailForm">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit" onclick="addEmail()" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: What difference is the parameter going to make? Please add the description to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to separate html markup and javascript code by assigning event handlers either by native javascript methods or those exposed with libraries such as jQuery. In the original code the `addEmail` function was called from an inline event handler with a single argument `e` which is generally assigned as the `event` ~ in this case `click`

As the function itself took a single argument `e` and the function was called with the same, non-quoted, argument `e` it referred to the actual click event and not the HTML element with name `e`. By explicitly referring to the element from within the function by name this problem is alleviated and the code triggers the `fetch` request OK but cannot be further tested due to being rejected by Google - error follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
        <script src='group.js'></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{


                const addEmail=function(){
                    let user = {
                        email: document.querySelector( 'input[name="e"]' ).value,
                        role: "MEMBER"
                    };
                    let group = "test@googlegroups.com";

                    /* what is $scope??? */
                    fetch( 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/'+ group +'/members',{ method: 'POST', body: $scope.user } )
                        .then( res => res.json() ) 
                        .then( json => console.log( json ) );
                }

                document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click',event=>{
                    addEmail.call( this );
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="emailForm">
            <input type="text" name="e" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The rejection error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```